Pourquoi la préférence pour le pronom impersonnel
Aujourd'hui, un de mes élèves a posé une excellente question. On avait comparé les deux phrases :

Des rivières coulent sur mes joues.
Sur mes joues il coule des rivières.

(Cette dernière apparaît dans une chanson de Daniel Lavoie.)
L'élève a demandé : « Pourquoi le français préfère-t-il le pronom impersonnel ici ? »
J'avais pas de réponse, j'ai juste dit que c'est aléatoire. Mais qu'est-ce que vous en pensez ?

Ne pas oublier aussi "sur mes joues coulent des rivières" (pour faire le lien avec Apollinaire )!

Sur mes joues il coule des rivières serait peut-être plus agréable avec une virgule: sur mes joues, il coule des rivières.

@None lol, c'est vrai. Et évidemment je ne change pas souvent d'exemples :)

Je dirais que le français ne « préfère » pas la tournure impersonnelle en général. À mon avis la tournure personnelle est celle qui sera spontanément écrite ou dite dans un contexte normal.

Des larmes coulent sur mes joues.

Le contexte dans laquelle cette phrase figure est spécifique. Il s'agit d'une chanson, et le parolier a besoin d'une rime et d'un nombre de syllabes pour le rythme. Il faut que le dernier mot rime avec « faire » donc « rivières » est en fin de phrase.
Du point de vue purement lexical l'ajout du pronom impersonnel ne s'imposait absolument pas et l'auteur aurait pu s'en tenir à « Sur mes joues coulent des rivières. »
La présence de ce pronom ajoute une syllabe supplémentaire à la phrase, peut-être cette syllabe permettait-elle une meilleure harmonie avec la musique.
Quand elle n'est pas obligatoire (ce qui est le cas avec certains verbes pleuvoir, neiger, falloir, etc.) je trouve la tournure impersonnelle plutôt lourde et je suis d'accord avec ce qui est dit dans ce billet du Bescherelle :

Rappelons que [l'emploi des tournures impersonnelles] alourdit inutilement et considérablement les textes [...]


« Sur mes joues coulent des rivières. » Absolumment. Surtout en poésie.
